# Paperclip alternative that works in Rails 4 and Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-activestorage

**Background**

- We have a legacy, monolith Rails 4.2 project.  Call it "Classic."
- "Classic" uses `Paperclip` for dealing with the storage of assets (photos, attachements, etc.) in a 3rd-party system.
- We are now breaking the monolith into multiple Rails 6 micro-services.  Call it "New".
- "Classic" and "New" share the same DB.

**The Goal**

- We want to stop using `Paperclip` because it is now deprecated and instead use `ActiveStorage`.

**The Problem**

- "Classic" and "New" are going to have to live at the same time for a while.
- "New" cannot use `Paperclip` because it's deprecated.
- "Classic" cannot use `ActiveStorage` because it requires at least `Rails 5.2`. ("Classic" cannot realistically be uplifted to 5.2)
- So we're stuck in a situation where "New" can use the newer technology, but it requires a DB change that "Classic" will not be compatible with and they share the same DB and "Classic" cannot use the newer technology.

**The Question**

- Has anyone else ever had to deal with a situation like this and was able to find an approach that worked?  Or maybe someone has another idea?

**My (potentially bad) Idea**

- Maybe we could go ahead and implement everything in "New" to use `ActiveStorage`.  We could provide some RESTful endpoints that would allow for the retrieval/create/update/destroy of 3rd-party hosted assets.
  Then in "Classic", anywhere that `Paperclip` is used, we could just replace that logic and have it make RESTful calls out to our new endpoints in "New".  Along with that, we'd also have to devise a strategy for identifying every asset that was managed via `Paperclip` and then create equivalent records over in the new `ActiveStorage` schema.  That way the logic in "New" would be able to access past assets.  I'm not sure if that is a realistic approach and it probably has some serious shortcomings that I'm overlooking, but it was a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [Paperclip to ActiveStorage Migration doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/MIGRATING.md) as a guide, I was able to workout a successful solution.

Here is what I did.

- In `New` I built the migration to add the 2 `ActiveStorage` tables.
- Ran the migration.
- Tweaked the `ConvertToActiveStorage` class (provided in the linked migration doc), to iterate over my "Paperclipized" items and in-turn create equivalent `ActiveStorage` records.  Note :: Rather than run the `ConvertToActiveStorage` as a migration, I set it up to be ran as a Rake task.
- Executed the `ConvertToActiveStorage` logic in `Classic`.
- Updated the models in `New` to begin working with `ActiveStorage` objects (rather than the old "Paperclipized" objects).  Basically changed from something like :: `has_one :photo, dependent: :destroy` to `has_one_attached :photo`
- In `Classic`, added `after_create`, `after_update` and `after_destroy` callbacks on the `Paperclipized` models.  Those callbacks are responsible for creating/updating/destroying the equivalent `ActiveStorage` records.  This allows for `Classic` ('Paperclipized') and `New` ('ActiveStorage structure') to exist for a while longer at the same time.  So when someone goes into `Classic` and adds a new user image, the callback will handle also going and creating the equivalent `ActiveStorage` records so that `New` will be able to interact with the user image.  Same idea for the update and delete.  Eventually, when `New` has the ability to create/update/destroy images, then I'll need to provide callbacks to go the other way (`ActiveStorage` to `Paperclip`) but that's a battle for a future day.